# My submit button is not working on my form_for in Rails - no error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am back for my second question.

My submit button on my form_for does not do anything when I click on it. I did have an error message in the console that said 'Unpermitted parameter: :photo_cache' however when I saw this I permitted the 'photo_cache' in the params in my controller, BUT the submit button on my form still doesn't work.

Context: I am trying to create a hairdressers which has the following params: name, description, location, photo and address.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@hairdresser) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <!-- [...] -->

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :address %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :location %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :photo %>
  <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %>
   </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, label: "Submit Form", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
  </div>
  <!-- [...] -->
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class HairdressersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hairdressers = Hairdresser.all
  end

  def show
    @hairdresser = Hairdresser.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @hairdresser = Hairdresser.new
  end

  def create
    @hairdresser = Hairdresser.new(hairdresser_params)
    # @hairdresser.save ? (redirect_to hairdresser_path(@hairdresser)) : (render 'new')
      if @hairdresser.save
        redirect_to hairdresser_path(@hairdresser)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def edit
    @hairdresser = Hairdresser.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @hairdresser =  Hairdresser.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @hairdresser =  Hairdresser.find(params[:id])
  end
end
private

def hairdresser_params
  params.require(:hairdresser).permit(:name, :address, :photo, :location, :description, :photo_cache)
end
```

My model:

```
class Hairdresser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true

  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

Comment: Seems like your form is missing a `form` tag?

Comment: I can't see the `<%= form_for ... %>`

Comment: Apologies both i didn't put my form inside the backticks here it is in full now

Comment: What is written to the log file when you try to make create request?

Comment: I have text, it says it is processing: 'Started POST "/hairdressers" for ::1 at 2019-04-08 16:29:14 +0100
`Processing by HairdressersController#create as HTML` Then there is no error but it says this: `(0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/hairdressers_controller.rb:18
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/hairdressers_controller.rb:18`

Comment: Well the ROLLBACK part means there was some error. Try temporarily changing `save` to `save!` and see what happens. Also what is `photo_cache` in relation to a hair dresser I think this is more than likely your issue

Comment: Hi engineersmnky ok so I changed it to `save!`  My form still did not save but now i have another error `Validation failed: User must exist`. Is this because my Hairdresser model belongs to a User ? The photo_cache param comes from the cloudinary photo uploaded I am using. When I do not add this to the permitted params in my controller it errors and says that `photo_cache is not permitted`.... Thanks in advance. I am rather lost with this one.

Comment: I found the reason after 4 hours :) I have posted it below. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Hi I actually found an answer to this online. Here is the answer for anyone who has lost time with this issue! :

"If you're on Rails 5, you'll need to update your user association to:

belongs_to :user, optional: true"